# Can Sasuke's Amaterasu go through windows?

Tags: naruto

I am not sure on whether you need to just see the object you want to cast it on, or if there must be a physically clear path to it.

Can the Amaterasu go through windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Amaterasu can pass through clear glass.

To quote the [wiki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Amaterasu)

> Amaterasu produces black flames at the focal point of the user's vision.
>   - *chapter 390 page 3*

The focal point of a users vision is located at the back of the on the retina as seen on the image below.

This means that whatever is being 'seen' by a user at that time, will be cast ablaze. Comparable to how you can either focus on something beyond a window, or if the window is dirty, the window it self.

[image]