# Can the Eternal Mangekyo Sharingan affect people without direct eye contact?

Tags: naruto

I was in a discussion today with a friend of mine about the strength of the Mangekyo Sharingan, and the question of "can the Eternal Mangekyo Sharingan affect people without direct eye contact?". We weren't certain, and lacked the materials to get an accurate result. Could someone help answer this question?

Comment: It really depends on the user. Shisui and Itachi's base Sharingan(they already unlocked Mangekyou, not Eternal, but not using it) did a genjutsu without eye contact.

Comment: To add to what @Albert said, it also depends on the jutsu being used. Susanoo, for example, if I remember correctly, do not require direct eye contact since it is partly defensive/offensive. But it can still affect other people.

Comment: @W.Are I think by "affect people without direct eye contact" he's talking about genjutsu. But I could be wrong.

Comment: @Albert Maybe. But his question is asking about the Eternal Mangekyo Sharingan, which encompasses and enhances abilities other than genjutsu that does not require eye contact. The way the question is phrased, he looks like as if he's asking if there is jutsu available to EMS user that do not require eye contact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're referring to genjutsu, since *Amaterasu* can burn a person even if they aren't making eye contact, and *Susano'o* can smash a person even if they aren't making eye contact.

The fight between Kabuto and Sasuke and Itachi in chapter 586 suggests that **eye contact is needed to cast genjutsu**, even if it's using an Eternal Mangekyou. During this fight, Sasuke had an Eternal Mangekyou, and Kabuto didn't seem terribly concerned.

> Kabuto: "Since I shut off my vision, genjutsu won't work on me. I tell you again, you two have no chance of winning."

However, *Izanami* can be cast on a person even without direct eye contact. This is explained in chapter 587:

> Sasuke: "So how? How can ocular jutsu work without eyesight?"
>
> Itachi: "The Izanami is an ocular jutsu... that works with the physical senses of yourself and your opponents."

*Izanami* is very special though, so this probably isn't the norm. After all, *Izanami* is an incredibly powerful jutsu that blinds the Sharingan that is used to cast it. The general expectation seems to be that ocular jutsu requires eye contact, regardless of whether the Sharingan is regular, Mangekyou, or Eternal Mangekyou.

---

Though note also that Itachi can cast genjutsu [from his finger](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Ephemeral). So even without Mangekyou, it doesn't need to be *direct* eye contact.

Comment: There's also the izanagi, which is the rumored twin jutsu of the izanami, this jutsu makes genjutsu and illusions a reality and does not require direct eye contact, as shown by both Danzou and Obito, but then, the jutsu's can only be used within a small duration, except the person posseses both uchiha and senju chakra. And also, the cost of loosing sight forever, makes the jutsu a one time kinda move. Moreover, both the izanami and izanagi do not require the eternal mangekyou, and can be used with normal sharingans

Comment: @Rumpel but that has nothing to do with the "strength of Eternal Mangekyou Sharingan" as the question clearly states?

Comment: If you completely read my comment, then you'll understand that i implied that when i said "Moreover, both the izanami and izanagi do not require the eternal mangekyou, and can be used with normal sharingans" @GKA

Answer (score 2):

I am going by the assumption that you mean, techniques that required eye contact previously, but after obtaining the EMS (eternal mangekyou sharingan) no longer do.

In which case, the answer would be *no*. The EMS allows users to tap into more techniques at less chakra cost. And more importantly, without the side effect of turning blind. But does not, for example, allow the Amaterasu to burn people without making eye contact. All though [It does not have to be direct eye contact](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/48039/1458).

Answer (score 2):

I assume you referring to use Genjutsu with Sharingan, because of physical ninjutsu did not require eye contact with the enemy to use it, like Amaterasu, Kamui, or etc.

Of course, it can. Even without using Eternal Mangenkyou Sharingan or ordinary Mangenkyou Sharingan Itachi can still use his Genjutsu through his finger (https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Ephemeral). Danzo can also use the Genjutsu from the Shishui's Sharingan eye that he stole to manipulate people even though the Sharingan eye always under his headband.

Answer (score 0):

Eternal Mangekyo simply means that the backlash caused to eyesight by use of Sharingan and Mangekyo Sharingan is not experienced by the user. It doesn't affect the technique to such a degree that if visual contact was required earlier, it won't be later on. However, a lot of techniques of mangekyo don't require eye contact. They will remain as it is, however as user won't feel the side effects, it gives a bit of a power boost to the technique

Comment: Please include relevant sources/references.